# Why does this variadic template specialization definition not compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, typelist

Using gcc 4.7.3, I get the following error

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: prog.cpp:27:63: error:
>   ‘Erase >::Result’ has not been
>   declared

with [this code](http://ideone.com/Q8sRG3):

```
template <typename... List>
struct TypeList
{
    enum
    {
        Length = sizeof...(List)
    };
};

template <typename ToErase, typename... List>
struct Erase;

template <typename ToErase>
struct Erase<ToErase, TypeList<>>
{
    typedef TypeList<> Result;
};

template <typename ToErase, typename... Head, typename... Tail>
struct Erase<ToErase, TypeList<Head..., ToErase, Tail...>>
{
    typedef TypeList<Head..., Tail...> Result;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(Erase<double, TypeList<int, double, char>>::Result::Length == 2, 
    "Did not erase double from TypeList<int, double, char>");

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the code doesn't compile given the error message I've received, given that a similar case does compile cleanly:

```
template <typename ToAppend, typename... List>
struct Append;

template <typename ToAppend, typename... List>
struct Append<ToAppend, TypeList<List...>>
{
    typedef TypeList<List..., ToAppend> Result;
}

template <typename... ToAppend, typename... List>
struct Append<TypeList<ToAppend...>, TypeList<List...>>
{
    typedef TypeList<List..., ToAppend...> Result;
}
```

Is there a quote from the standard about not being able to deduce elements in the middle of two parameter packs like I'm trying to do with the first block of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§ 14.8.2.5 (Deducing template arguments from a type) paragraph 5 lists the contexts in which template arguments cannot be deduced. The relevant one is the last one in the list:

> — A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-clause.

So in:

```
struct Erase<ToErase, TypeList<Head..., ToErase, Tail...>>
```

`Head` cannot be deduced; it does not occur at the end of a parameter list.

By contrast, in:

```
struct Append<TypeList<ToAppend...>, TypeList<List...>>
```

Both `ToAppend` and `List` appear at the end of their respective parameter lists, and hence they can be deduced.