# How can I use Variadic templates to flatten a tree of types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I have a construct like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct List {}

typedef List<char,List<int,float,List<int,unsigned char>>,List<unsigned,short>> MyList;
```

and I want to essentially flatten it to one list. What is the best way? I think I could make something with recursion if I fiddle with it long enough but something tells me there should be a better way.

What I want as a result of the above tree should be similar to this:

```
typedef List<char,int,float,int,unsigned char,unsigned,short> FlattenedList;
```

Here is my first attempt:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct List{};

template<typename... Ts>
struct FlattenTree{
    typedef List<Ts...> Type;
};
template<typename... Ts, typename... Us, typename... Vs>
struct FlattenTree<Ts...,List<Us...>,Vs...>{
    typedef typename FlattenTree<Ts..., Us..., Vs...>::Type Type;
};
```

but it results in this error: `error C3515: if an argument for a class template partial specialization is a pack expansion it shall be the last argument`

rici pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332286/why-does-this-variadic-template-specialization-definition-not-compile) what MSVC2013 is complaining about, so no compiler bug here:

§ 14.8.2.5 (Deducing template arguments from a type) paragraph 5 lists the contexts in which template arguments cannot be deduced. The relevant one is the last one in the list:

```
— A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-clause.
```

**Update:**

I guess one could put in a dummy parameter at the very end, keep moving the first argument to the end or expanding it to the front if its a List and specialize on the first parameter being my dummy to stop recursion. That seems like a lot of work for the compiler just to flatten a list though.

```
namespace Detail{
    struct MyMagicType {};
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct FlattenTree{
        typedef typename FlattenTree<Ts..., T>::Type Type;
    };
    template<typename... Ts>
    struct FlattenTree<MyMagicType,Ts...>{      //termination case
        typedef List<Ts...> Type;
    };
    template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
    struct FlattenTree<List<Ts...>, Us...>{
        typedef typename FlattenTree<Ts..., Us...>::Type Type;
    };              //expand Ts to front because they may hold more nested Lists
}

template<typename... Ts>
struct FlattenTree{
    typedef typename Detail::FlattenTree<Ts...,Detail::MyMagicType>::Type Type;
};
```

This works on MSVC2013 but I don't think its the best way possible since I needed a dummy type and it puts a lot of load on the compiler. I want to use it with lists containing 500+ elements.

Comment: I recall hearing that many compilers (sans clang) have problems with template classes with more than a couple template parameters.  There's a reason a lot of the C++03 "variadic templates" only went to 6-12 parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to use a helper class and an accumulator list instead of `MyMagicType`. We start with an empty `List<>` and then fill it with types from the input list:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class... Ts> struct List {};

// first parameter - accumulator
// second parameter - input list
template <class T, class U>
struct flatten_helper;

// first case - the head of the List is List too
// expand this List and continue
template <class... Ts, class... Heads, class... Tail>
struct flatten_helper<List<Ts...>, List<List<Heads...>, Tail...>> {
    using type = typename flatten_helper<List<Ts...>, List<Heads..., Tail...>>::type;
};

// second case - the head of the List is not a List
// append it to our new, flattened list
template <class... Ts, class Head, class... Tail>
struct flatten_helper<List<Ts...>, List<Head, Tail...>> {
    using type = typename flatten_helper<List<Ts..., Head>, List<Tail...>>::type;
};

// base case - input List is empty
// return our flattened list
template <class... Ts>
struct flatten_helper<List<Ts...>, List<>> {
    using type = List<Ts...>;
};

// wrapper around flatten_helper
template <class T> struct flatten;

// start with an empty accumulator
template <class... Ts>
struct flatten<List<Ts...>> {
    using type = typename flatten_helper<List<>, List<Ts...>>::type;
};

auto main() -> int {
    using Types = List<int, List<float, List<double, List<char>>>>;
    using Flat = flatten<Types>::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<Flat, List<int, float, double, char>>::value, "Not the same");
}
```

Comment: for a list that is pretty flat already (no so deeply nested) this is probably far less complexity because it does far less iterations than mine

Comment: @PorkyBrain Hmm, it seems to be the same to me. One recursive call for every type and for every `List`.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is quite elegant IMO, here's another one off the top of my head:

```
// the tuple-like class we want to flatten
// (i.e. the node of the tree, with several children as template parameters)
template<class... TT>
struct List
{};


// a join metafunction. Joins multiple Lists into a single List
// e.g.    List<TT1...>, List<TT2...>, etc., List<TTN...>
//      => List<TT1..., TT2..., etc., TTN...>
// requires: all template arguments are `List<..>`s
template<class... TT>
struct join
{
    using type = List<>; // end recursion for no parameters
};

template<class... TT>
struct join<List<TT...>>
{
    using type = List<TT...>; // end recursion for a single parameter
};

template<class... TT0, class... TT1, class... TT2>
struct join<List<TT0...>, List<TT1...>, TT2...>
{
    // join two adjacent lists into one, recurse
    // by joining the two lists `List<TT0...>` and `List<TT1...>`,
    // we get one template argument less for the next instantiation of `join`
    // this recurs until there's only one argument left, which then
    // matches the specialization `struct join<List<TT...>>`
    using type = typename join< List<TT0..., TT1...>, TT2... > :: type;
};


// the flatten metafunction
// guarantees (all specializations): the nested `type` is a flat `List<..>`
template<class T>
struct flatten
{
    // because of the partial specialization below,
    // this primary template is only used if `T` is not a `List<..>`
    using type = List<T>; // wrap the argument in a `List`
};

template<class... TT>
struct flatten<List<TT...>> // if the argument is a `List` of multiple elements
{
    // then flatten each element of the `List` argument
    // and join the resulting `List<..>`s
    using type = typename join<typename flatten<TT>::type...>::type;

    // ex. the argument is `List<List<int>, List<double>>`
    // then `TT...` is deduced to `List<int>, List<double>`
    // `List<int>` flattened is `List<int>`, similarly for `List<double>`
    // `join< List<int>, List<double> >` yields `List<int, double>`
};
```

Usage and test code:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
void print(T)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; // NON-STANDARD
}

int main()
{
    typedef List<char,List<int,float,List<int,unsigned char>>,
                 List<unsigned,short>> MyList;
    print( flatten<MyList>::type{} );
}
```

I'm sure the simplest way is to use boost::MPL ;)

Comment: Does the boost MPL make proper use of variadics? I can't even get boost 1.54 to compile correctly with MSVC2013 so I can't imagine they are up to date.

Comment: @DyP could you please add comments to the code. I am having hard time understanding this(I'm trying to understand this multiple parameter packs in general so). Thank you.

Comment: i dint understand this line `join< List<TT0..., TT1...>, TT2... > :: type;
`. which template is it going to instantiate? `struct join<List<TT...>>
` right?

Comment: @Koushik That depends on `TT2...`. Essentially `struct join<List<TT0...>, List<TT1...>, TT2...>` combines the first and second `List` recursively until there's only one `List` left, which then matches `struct join<List<TT...>>`.

Comment: oh thanks a lot. this is a really beautiful design. how did you think of this design? can you suggest any sources which I can use to strengthen my template skills? especially variadics? than you once again:-)

Comment: @Koushik Thank you. As I said in my answer, I find the solution of the OP quite elegant, as it's very compact. There's also [Yakk's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20953039/420683) which is designed to be comprehensible. [Khurshid's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2542308/khurshid) [(old account)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2614655/khurshid-normuradov) questions have been quite a source of inspiration (restrictions boost creativity ;) As for other sources: I'm not sure if there's already a well-established post-C++11 TMP book; you might find talks and blogs about specific sub-topics.

Comment: @DyP thanks for the suggestions. I will utilize these resources and then build from there. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using a generic "Meta-Tree-Traversal":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
struct HasChildren : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct HasChildren<P<Types...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename, typename> struct Visit;
template <typename, typename, bool> struct VisitHelper;
template <typename, typename> struct LeafAction;

// Here the role of P2<Visited...> is simply to allow LeafAction to carry out its function.  It is not native to the tree structure itself.
template <template <typename...> class P1, template <typename...> class P2, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Visited>
struct Visit<P1<First, Rest...>, P2<Visited...>> :
    VisitHelper<P1<First, Rest...>, P2<Visited...>, HasChildren<First>::value> {};

template <template <typename...> class P1, template <typename...> class P2, typename... Visited>
struct Visit<P1<>, P2<Visited...>> {  // End of recursion.  Every leaf in the tree visited.
    using result = P2<Visited...>;
};

// Here First has children, so visit its children, after which visit Rest...
template <template <typename...> class P1, template <typename...> class P2, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Visited>
struct VisitHelper<P1<First, Rest...>, P2<Visited...>, true> : Visit<P1<Rest...>, typename Visit<First, P2<Visited...>>::result> {};  // Visit the "subtree" First, and then after that visit Rest...  Need to use ::result so that when visiting Rest..., the latest value of the P2<Visited...> pack is used.

// Here First has no children, so the "leaf action" is carried out. 
template <template <typename...> class P1, template <typename...> class P2, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Visited>
struct VisitHelper<P1<First, Rest...>, P2<Visited...>, false> : LeafAction<P1<First, Rest...>, P2<Visited...>> {};

// As a simple example, the leaf action shall simply be appending its type to P<Visited...>.
template <template <typename...> class P1, template <typename...> class P2, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Visited>
struct LeafAction<P1<First, Rest...>, P2<Visited...>> : Visit<P1<Rest...>, P2<Visited..., First>> {};  // Having visited First, now visit Rest...

template <typename> struct VisitTree;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct VisitTree<P<Types...>> : Visit<P<Types...>, P<>> {};

// ---------------------------- Testing ----------------------------
template <typename...> struct Pack;

template <typename Last>
struct Pack<Last> {
    static void print() {std::cout << typeid(Last).name() << std::endl;}
};

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct Pack<First, Rest...> {
    static void print() {std::cout << typeid(First).name() << ' ';  Pack<Rest...>::print();}
};

template <typename...> struct Group;
template <typename...> struct Wrap;
struct Object {};

int main() {
    VisitTree<
        Pack<Pack<int, Object, double>, bool, Pack<char, Pack<int, double, Pack<char, Pack<char, long, short>, int, Object>, char>, double>, long>
    >::result::print();  // int Object double bool char int double char char long short int Object char double long

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<
        VisitTree<Pack<Wrap<int, Object, double>, bool, Group<char, Pack<int, double, Pack<char, Wrap<char, long, short>, int, Object>, char>, double>, long>>::result,
        Pack<int, Object, double, bool, char, int, double, char, char, long, short, int, Object, char, double, long>
    >::value << std::endl;  // true
}
```