# template metaprogramming :why flat type is failure

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to flatten a tree type to flat type. Example:

```
typedef std::tuple<int,std::tuple<int,long>,int> tup; 
Flat<tup>::type=>std::tuple<int,int,long,int>
```

I use:

```
template<typename T>
struct Flat
{
    using type=T;
};
template <template <typename ...> class C,typename...ARGS>
struct Flat<C<ARGS...> >
{
    using type=C<ARGS...>;
};
template <template <typename ...> class C,typename ...ARGS0,typename...ARGS1,typename ...ARGS2>
struct Flat<C<ARGS0...,C<ARGS1...>,ARGS2...> >
:Flat<C<ARGS0...,ARGS1...,ARGS2...> >
{

};

void test(){
typedef std::tuple<int,std::tuple<int,long>,int> tup;
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Flat<tup>::type,std::tuple<int,int,long,int> >::value,"");
}
```

but I get `std::tuple<int,std::tuple<int,long>,int>` still... I use gcc 4.8.1

Comment: You don't need the middle partial specialisation (the one for `C<ARGS...>`). What happens when you remove it?

Comment: @Angew if  I remove it .not work still.

Comment: The partial specialization `Flat<C<Args0...,C<Args1...>,Args2...>>` cannot be used: The `Args0` already matches all template-arguments of `C` so that `Args1` and `Args2` cannot be deduced. clang++ gives this warning: *warning: class template partial specialization contains template parameters that can not be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used*

Comment: [Here's a non-minimal solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7b5fa5ccfedad2d). Unfortunately, it works fine with clang++, but fails to compile with g++4.8.1 When replacing the template template-parameter `TT` with `std::tuple`, g++ also accepts it, which leads me to conclude that *not accepting it* is a g++ bug.

Comment: @DyP I noticed your comment too late :/

Comment: @Vinzenz no problem, your solution also works for g++4.8.1 (which the OP is using)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Variadic templates to flatten a tree of types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838965/how-can-i-use-variadic-templates-to-flatten-a-tree-of-types)

Comment: @DyP,have same duplicate.but "How can I use Variadic templates to flatten a tree of types? " Against special List.I want to:`typedef std::tuple<int,std::tuple<int,long>,List<int,long> > tup; 
Flat<tup>::type=>std::tuple<int,int,long,List<int,long> >` it mean:only expand Outermost template class type .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my stab at this.  I tried to document what is going on to make it clear:

We start with Flatten.  It takes a type.  We will specialize it below:

```
template<typename T>
struct Flatten;
```

Here is our workhorse.  Takes Src, and flattens its contents and appends it to Dest:

```
template<typename Dest, typename Src>
struct Flatten_append;
```

An empty right hand side pack means return left hand side:

```
template<template<typename...>class Pack, typename... LHS>
struct Flatten_append< Pack<LHS...>, Pack<> > {
  typedef Pack<LHS...> type;
};
```

A right hand side whose first argument is a Pack<...> should be flattened before processing:

```
template<template<typename...>class Pack, typename... LHS, typename... RHS0, typename... RHSrest>
struct Flatten_append< Pack<LHS...>, Pack<Pack<RHS0...>, RHSrest... > >:
  Flatten_append< Pack<LHS...>, Pack< RHS0..., RHSrest... > >
{};
```

Otherwise, a non-empty right hand side pack should have its first element moved over to the left hand side: (this will match weaker than the above, as it is less specialized)

```
template<template<typename...>class Pack, typename... LHS, typename RHS0, typename... RHSrest>
struct Flatten_append< Pack<LHS...>, Pack<RHS0, RHSrest... > >:
  Flatten_append< Pack<LHS..., RHS0>, Pack< RHSrest... > >
{};
```

Implement Flatten in terms of Flatten_append to an empty Pack:

```
template<template<typename...>class Pack, typename... Ts>
struct Flatten< Pack<Ts...> >:Flatten_append< Pack<>, Pack<Ts...> > {};
```

The goal was to make it as clear what is going on as possible.

Now, you'll note that a downside to this design is that it will flatten *any* `template` that only contains types.  We probably want to pass in the pack that we want to flatten.

```
template<template<typename...>class Pack, typename T>
struct Flatten;

template<template<typename...>class Pack, typename Dest, typename Src>
struct Flatten_append;

template<template<typename...>class Pack, typename... Ts>
struct Flatten< Pack<Ts...> > : Flatten_append< Pack, Pack<>, Pack<Ts...> > {};
```

and then change each specialization of `Flatten_append< blah, blah, blah >` to `Flatten_append< Pack, blah, blah, blah >`.

This means you pass in the `template` you want to flatten explicitly, and the code only flattens that `template`.

In practice, this may not be needed, as the `Pack` type gets deduced from the left hand side type passed in.

Answer (score 4):

First the explanation of how this works:

This is a forward declaration so that we can use `flatten` with a single type.

```
template<class T>
struct flatten;
```

Then we specialize `flatten` to accept any template type.
`C` is a template template parameter so we can get the type of the surrounding template.
E.g. if you would use `flatten` with the parameter `std::tuple<int, double>` then `C` would be `std::tuple`.

FArgs is used to retrieve the parameter list of the template passed. In the case of the example I just referred to, it would be `int, double`

```
template< template< typename ... > class C, typename ...FArgs>                  
struct flatten<C<FArgs...>>
```

The rest of the `flatten` implementation now has always access to `C` the wrapper type and `FArgs` the list of arguments.

Forward declaration for `append` which appends the parameter `B` to the list of items in parameter `Target`

```
    template< typename Target, typename B >                                  
    struct append;
```

The specialization of `append` which retrieves the list of types from `Target` (see above).
Note that `C` here still is `std::tuple`.

So we're adding one more item to the list and creating a new type by applying the previous list of arguments `Args1` and then adding `T`

```
    template< typename ...Args1, typename T >
    struct append<C<Args1...>, T> {
        using type = C<Args1..., T>;
    };
```

Forward declaration of `inner` and `inner2`

`inner` is used to iterate through the list of arguments provided and applies `inner2` on each of them, which in turn again applies `inner` on the type, if the type is another template with parameters. This template must be the matched template `C`

```
    template< typename Target, typename ...Args >
    struct inner;

    template< typename Target, typename T >                                     
    struct inner2;
```

This `inner2` handles all `C` template types and recursively iterates through its parameter  list with the help of `inner`

```
    template< typename Target, typename ...Args>                                
    struct inner2<Target, C<Args...>> {                                         
        using type = typename inner<Target, Args...>::type;                     
    };
```

If this `inner2` specialization is used, the type will be appended to the end result.

```
    template< typename Target, typename T >                                     
    struct inner2 {                                                             
        using type = typename append<Target, T>::type;                          
    };
```

Recurses through the template parameters by inheriting and applying on each parameter `inner2`

```
    template< typename Target, typename T, typename ...Args>                    
    struct inner<Target, T, Args...>                                            
    : inner<typename inner2<Target, T>::type, Args...>                          
    {};
```

End condition for the recursion.

```
    template< typename Target, typename T >                                     
    struct inner<Target, T>                                                     
    {                                                                           
        using type = typename inner2<Target, T>::type;                          
    };
```

Here the whole thing from above gets triggered, `C<>` specifies the `Target` and `FArgs` are the arguments extracted by the `flatten` specialization.

```
    using type = typename inner<C<>, FArgs...>::type;                           
};
```

---

And here the whole code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template<class T>
struct flatten;

template< template< typename ... > class C, typename ...FArgs>                  
struct flatten<C<FArgs...>>                                                     
{                                                                               
    template< typename Target, typename ...B >                                  
    struct append;                                                              

    template< typename ...Args1, typename T >                                   
    struct append<C<Args1...>, T> {                                             
        using type = C<Args1..., T>;                                            
    };                                                                          

    template< typename Target, typename ...Args >                               
    struct inner;                                                               

    template< typename Target, typename T >                                     
    struct inner2;                                                              

    template< typename Target, typename ...Args>                                
    struct inner2<Target, C<Args...>> {                                         
        using type = typename inner<Target, Args...>::type;                     
    };                                                                          

    template< typename Target, typename T >                                     
    struct inner2 {                                                             
        using type = typename append<Target, T>::type;                          
    };                                                                          

    template< typename Target, typename T, typename ...Args>                    
    struct inner<Target, T, Args...>                                            
    : inner<typename inner2<Target, T>::type, Args...>                          
    {};                                                                         

    template< typename Target, typename T >                                     
    struct inner<Target, T>                                                     
    {                                                                           
        using type = typename inner2<Target, T>::type;                          
    };                                                                          

    using type = typename inner<C<>, FArgs...>::type;                           
};

int main() {                                                                    

    typedef flatten<std::tuple<int, float, double>>::type first;                
    static_assert(std::is_same<first, std::tuple<int, float, double>>::value, "First not the same");

    typedef flatten<std::tuple<int, std::tuple<float, double>>>::type second;   
    static_assert(std::is_same<second, std::tuple<int, float, double>>::value, "Second not the same");

    typedef flatten<std::tuple<int, std::tuple<char const *>, std::tuple<std::tuple<float, int>, double>>>::type third;
    static_assert(std::is_same<third, std::tuple<int, char const *, float, int, double>>::value, "Third not the same");

    typedef flatten<std::tuple<int, std::tuple<std::tuple<std::tuple<std::tuple<char const *>>>>, std::tuple<std::tuple<float, int>, double>>>::type fourth;
    static_assert(std::is_same<fourth, std::tuple<int, char const *, float, int, double>>::value, "Fourth not the same");

    typedef flatten<std::tuple<int, std::tuple<std::tuple<std::tuple<std::tuple<std::string>>>>, std::tuple<std::tuple<float, int>, double>>>::type fifth;
    static_assert(std::is_same<fifth, std::tuple<int, std::string, float, int, double>>::value, "Fifth not the same");
}
```

Edit: I have rewritten the implementation to make it more readable and shorter (inspired by @DyP)
Edit2: Explained the code

Comment: @DyP fixed ;) Thanks for testing :-)

Comment: Ah, now I can see the recursion :)

Comment: @DyP thanks for your example, I have rewritten the example to be more like yours, which works on g++ and clang++ :-)

Comment: @Vinzenz could you please add comments explaining the code? or even better an explaination? I am having difficulty understanding this useage of variadics. thank you.

Comment: @Koushik I have added the a detailed explanation how this works. Please add another comment if you're missing something.

Comment: @Vinzenz beautiful. thank you for the clean explanation. i understood the code and this is a really good implementation. thanks again :-)