# Build a specific tuple from a function's variadic argument

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, template-meta-programming

I like to build a "map" using `std::tuple`, the key is `std::string`, the value is any type, it's defined as following:

```
template<typename... Args>
using Map = std::tuple<std::pair<std::string, Args>...>;
```

And I have a function `MakeMap`, which accepts variadic arguments, to turn the arguments into a `Map` and returns it:

```
template<typename... Args>
Map<???> MakeMap(Args&&... args) {
    ???
}
```

And I'd like the arguments of `MakeMap` to be in `std::string, type1, std::string, type2, ...` format (a key followed by a value), for example:

```
auto map = MakeMap("key1", 42, "key2", "hello world"); // OK
auto map = MakeMap(1, 2);                              // expects compiling error
auto map = MakeMap("key1", 42, "key2");                // expects compiling error
```

So, how to implement the function `MakeMap` (in C++11), to make the above call syntax work?

Thanks.

---

### EDIT

Finally I figured it out with @Kostas's great help, thanks!

1. Pairs the arguments first:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct MapType;

template<>
struct MapType<> {
    using type = typename std::tuple<>;
};

template<typename K, typename V, typename... Args>
struct MapType<K, V, Args...> {
    using type = std::tuple<std::pair<std::string, V>, typename MapType<Args...>::type>;
};
```

2. Now we get a nested `std::tuple`, we need to flatten it (the following code snippet is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19840856/1256392), thanks to the original author):

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct FlattenHelper;

template<typename... Args, typename... Heads, typename... Tails>
struct FlattenHelper<std::tuple<Args...>, std::tuple<std::tuple<Heads...>, Tails...>> {
    using type = typename FlattenHelper<std::tuple<Args...>, std::tuple<Heads..., Tails...>>::type;
};

template<typename... Args, typename Head, typename... Tails>
struct FlattenHelper<std::tuple<Args...>, std::tuple<Head, Tails...>> {
    using type = typename FlattenHelper<std::tuple<Args..., Head>, std::tuple<Tails...>>::type;
};

template<typename... Args>
struct FlattenHelper<std::tuple<Args...>, std::tuple<>> {
    using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct Flatten;

template<typename... Args>
struct Flatten<std::tuple<Args...>> {
    using type = typename FlattenHelper<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
};
```

3. Now we can define `MakeMap` like this:

```
template<typename... Args>
using ReturnType = typename Flatten<typename MapType<Args...>::type>::type;

template<typename K, typename V, typename... Args>
ReturnType<K, V, Args...> MakeMap(K&& k, V&& v, Args&&... args) {
    // `std::forward` is omitted here
    return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::make_pair(k, v)), MakeMap(args...));
}

std::tuple<> MakeMap() {
    return std::tuple<>();
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what led you to want to create something like this?

Comment: @Kosta We are building a schema-less RPC framework, and might communicate with other dynamic languages like Lua and JavaScript, so we have to simulate tables in Lua and objects in Javascript, and we cannot simply use JSON due to some historical reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual `std::index_sequence` to the rescue (C++14, but can be implemented in C++11):

```
// C++14 alias
template <typename T>
using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
using tuple_element_t = typename std::tuple_element<I, T>::type;

template <std::size_t...Is, typename Tuple>
Map<decay_t<tuple_element_t<2 * Is + 1, Tuple>>...>
MakeMapImpl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& t)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::make_pair(std::get<2 * Is>(t),
                                          std::get<2 * Is + 1>(t))...);
}

template <typename... Args>
auto MakeMap(Args&&... args)
-> decltype(MakeMapImpl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) / 2>(), std::make_tuple(args...)))
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0, "!");

    return MakeMapImpl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) / 2>(), std::make_tuple(args...));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/445ebfe23a453449)

Comment: Wow, this is impressive and elegant! I never realized the power of `auto`/`decltype` combination!

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you for posting this. Since you seem to know your way around templates would you mind helping me understand what's wrong with the error I'm getting in my answer? (feel free to edit if it's something small)

Answer (score 2):

Below is a way of achieving this (with a few changes)

Due to inability of template deduction from implicit object construction, we unfortunately have to either specify the template arguments, or explicitly initialize the arguments.

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
using Map = std::tuple<std::pair<std::string, Args>...>;

template<typename... Args>
Map<Args...> MakeMap(std::pair<std::string,Args>... args) {
  return Map<Args...>{args...};
}

int main() {
  auto map  = MakeMap<int, std::string>({"hello", 1}, {"hey", "ho"});
  auto map2 = MakeMap(std::pair<std::string, int>        {"hello", 1},
                      std::pair<std::string, std::string>{"hey", "ho"});
}
```

Alternatively, something closer to what you wanted (C++14):

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<typename... Args>
using Map = std::tuple<std::pair<std::string, Args>...>;

// declaration
template<typename ...T_Args>
auto MakeMap(T_Args...);

// empty case
template<>
auto MakeMap() {
  return std::tuple<>();
}

// inductive map case
template<typename K, typename V, typename ...T_Args>
auto MakeMap(K&& k, V&& v, T_Args&& ...V_Args) {
  static_assert(std::is_convertible<K, std::string>::value, "keys should be strings");
  static_assert(sizeof...(T_Args) % 2 == 0,                 "keys must have values" );

  return std::tuple_cat( // concatenate current key-value to the rest of the map
             std::tuple<std::pair<std::string,V>(
                 std::pair<std::string, V>(std::forward<K>(k),std::forward<V>(v))),
             MakeMap<T_Args...>(std::forward<T_Args>(V_Args)...));
}

int main() {
  auto map = MakeMap("key1", 42, "key2", "hello world"); // OK                                                                                                                       
  //auto map2 = MakeMap(1, 2);                           // Error: "keys should be strings"                                                                                          
  //auto map3 = MakeMap("key1", 42, "key2");             // Error: "keys must have values"                                                                                           
}
```

To use `C++11` you need to deduct the return types by hand:

*This is done below*

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<typename ...Args>
using Map = std::tuple<std::pair<std::string, Args>...>;

// deriving type of Map given arguments to MakeMap                                                                                                                                                                 
template<typename ...Args> struct Map_tp;

template<>
struct Map_tp<> { using type = typename std::tuple<>; };

template<typename K, typename V, typename ...Args>
struct Map_tp<K,V,Args...> {
  using tuple_cat_tp = decltype(&std::tuple_cat<std::tuple<std::pair<std::string,V>>,
                                               typename Map_tp<Args...>::type>);

  using type =
    typename std::result_of<tuple_cat_tp(typename std::tuple<std::pair<std::string,V>>,
                                         typename Map_tp<Args...>::type)>::type;
};

// defining MakeMap                                                                                                                                                                                                
template<typename ...T_Args>
typename Map_tp<T_Args...>::type MakeMap(T_Args...);

// base case                                                                                                                                                                                                       
template<>
typename Map_tp<>::type
MakeMap() {
  return std::tuple<>();
}

// inductive case                                                                                                                                                                                                  
template<typename K, typename V, typename ...T_Args>
typename Map_tp<K,V,T_Args...>::type
MakeMap(K&& k, V&& v, T_Args&& ...V_Args) {
  static_assert(std::is_convertible<K, std::string>::value, "keys should be strings");
  static_assert(sizeof...(T_Args) % 2 == 0, "keys must have values");

  return std::tuple_cat(
              std::tuple<std::pair<std::string,V>>(
                   std::pair<std::string, V>(std::forward<K>(k),std::forward<V>(v))),
              MakeMap<T_Args...>(std::forward<T_Args>(V_Args)...));
}

int main() {
  auto map = MakeMap("key1", 42, "key2", "hello world"); // OK                                                                                                                                                     
  //auto map2 = MakeMap(1, 2);                           // Error: "keys should be strings"                                                                                                                        
  //auto map3 = MakeMap("key1", 42, "key2");             // Error: "keys must have values"                                                                                                                         
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a5ecc9f94b21a83)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, the problem is that we can use only C++11 (the company does not allow to use a new compiler), so return `auto` from function is not supported, that's the main reason I asked the question, I need a way to figure out the return type.

Comment: I finally figured it out, I updated the solution in the question's **EDIT** section, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @KelvinHu Well done! You should rather post your own answer and accept it :)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your advice, however, I accepted Kostas's answer, as I cannot figure out it without his help.

Comment: @KelvinHu that's just how the site works, only the question up top and answers in the answers section. No harm in awarding the checkmark to whomever you wish though.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your suggestion, I have accepted the answer posted by Jarod42, it's really impressive and elegant. And I really appreciate Kostas's help. Thank you all, and have a nice day!

Comment: @KelvinHu You too mate!

Comment: Error fixed. `using type =
    decltype(tuple_cat_tp(std::declval<std::tuple<std::pair<std::string,V>>(),
                                        std::declval<typename Map_tp<Args...>::type>()));` seems simpler though.
Or simply get rid of `Map_tp` and use `template </*..*/>auto f(/*..*/) -> decltype (Expr) { return Expr; }`.